# Org-mode list with a mix of unordered and description list items?

Tags: org-mode

It seems that all items in plain text unordered list have to contain descriptions, otherwise the HTML export is incorrect.

Example:

```
- item1 :: item1 description bla bla bla
- item2
- item3
```

then I export it to HTML, the result is

```
item1
  item1 description bla bla bla
(no terms)
  item2
(no terms)
  item3
```

I see that item2 and item3 are exported incorrectly as if the original test was `no terms :: item2`?

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to mix unordered list and description list at the same indentation level? Have a look at the example here for different list types: http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html. You used the `- term :: definition` format for the first item in the list. So org-mode is expecting the same for the rest too.

Comment: you are right, I would like to have the mix. It is very natural for me that unordered list items will or will not have description. So if there is no `::`, then it is by default a term, if there is `::` then it is `term::description`.

Comment: So in effect you want the whole list to be a **description** list, but you want a default term for the items where you don't have `term ::`? What is that default term? Out of curiosity why do you need such a list with default term fields?

Comment: I think I have knowledge gap here. But no, I don't want a default term. I want my text to be interpreted as the term when there is no `::` and `description` after the text. However in the HTML export, if `::` and `description` are not given, the text is interpreted as description of `no terms`

Comment: I have edited your question title for clarity. Feel free to revert it if that is not right. I don't think you can have a mixed list like that. If you want, you can have a "description-like" item by simply emboldening the term portion: `- *term* description`.

Comment: Can you just add :: without a description?

Comment: @XiXiao -  How did you expect `org-mode` render the list? Adding your expectations will help make your question better.

Comment: @XiXiao - Do any of current answers help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### This is the expected behavior.

> A list ends whenever every item has ended, which means before any line less or equally indented than items at top level. It also ends before two blank lines. In that case, all items are closed.<sup>[1](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#fnd-5)</sup>

When switching between the different kinds of [plain lists](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html), i.e. unordered, ordered and description, `org-mode` will need the end of each list to be clearly defined.

In your example

```
    - item1 :: item1 description bla bla bla
    - item2
    - item3
```

the list begins as a **description list** and immediately transitions into an **unordered list**.

---

To switch between types provide a clear ending to each type of list:

#### Option 1 - Indent description list under an empty unordered list.

```
    -
      - item1 :: item1 description bla bla bla
    - item2
    - item3
```

exports to html as

```html
<ul class="org-ul">
        <li><dl class="org-dl">
                <dt> item1 </dt><dd>item1 description bla bla bla
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </li>
        <li>item2
        </li>
        <li>item3
        </li>
</ul>
```

And will render like this

> - **item1**
>   item1 description bla bla bla
> - item2
> - item3

**I recommend this option 1**

---

#### Option 2 - Create 2 lists by adding 2 blank lines after description list.

```
 - item1 :: item1 description bla bla bla


 - item2
 - item3
```

will export to html as

```html
<dl class="org-dl">
        <dt> item1 </dt><dd>item1 description bla bla bla
                        </dd>
</dl>


<ul class="org-ul">
        <li>item2
        </li>
        <li>item3
        </li>
</ul>
```

And will render like this

> **item1**
> item1 description bla bla bla
>
> - item2
> - item3

This answer was tested using

> GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
> of 2014-11-14
>
> org-version: 8.2.10

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, this should work:

```
- item1 :: item1 description bla bla bla
- item2 ::
- item3 ::
```

This produces:

**item1**
        item1 description bla bla bla
**item2**
**item3**

Comment: indeed this should work, but add empty `::` for those items without description is somehow futile work. Assume I have list with 10 items and only first has description, then I need to add `::` for remainder 9 items..I expect org-mode to be smarter