# In Org, how can I mix ordered and unordered lists (numbers and bullets) at the same indentation level?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I'm new to org mode, and I'm trying to figure out if something like this is possible, and if so, how to do realize it:

```
* Unordered
    1. Ordered
    2. Ordered
    *  UNORDERED
* Unordered
```

The key is to have UNORDERED at the same indentation level as the numbered items.

Comment: You can always manually adjust the indentation in the Org mode file to suit your taste (after all, Org mode files are just text files), so of course you can do it. But what does it mean? What do you expect should happen if you export to some format? I suspect that the answer you get  is going to be disappointing, but it's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: To follow up with what @NickD asked: what behavior are you really trying to get? Is there an aim behind wanting bullets and numbers at the same indentation level? Is your question as asked perhaps an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: While [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17244/org-mode-list-with-a-mix-of-unordered-and-description-list-items) isn't exactly the same, the answers should be applicable to the question here too.